# Properties of a Radon balloon

Tags: science-based, physics, gas, radioactivity

I have a regular-old rubber balloon and I want to fill it up with Radon. As luck may have it, I recently stumbled across a magical Radon-generator at a military-surplus sale. What would happen if I tried to fill my balloon with Radon?

- Would it be incredibly heavy?
- What about radiation? Would it become hot to the touch, or cause the balloon to burst? (And what would happen over time, as the Radon decays?
- As a bonus, what would happen if a breathed it in and tried to sound like Darth Vader?

Comment: 6 questions here (only one per post). I'm not seeing a worldbuilding problem to solve.

Comment: Angry Muppet's right, it's going to be hard to answer all questions at once. Also, to be considered worldbuilding you should explain why it's paramount to have a radon balloon in your fictional world, it's really not obvious right now ^^".

Comment: @Tortliena, my character finds a radon generator at a military surplus sale and fills up a radon balloon.

Comment: Perhaps to remind yourself how we work re-read the [ask] section of the [help].

Comment: What exactly is the worldbuilding problem you're trying to solve? Am voting to close because there's no obvious problem you're trying to solve. Also, am downvoting  because you don't seem to have done any basic research.

Comment: Radon is remarkably difficult to produce, and is therefore quite expensive. Getting a balloonful is a challenge. This is probably a good thing, because with a half-life of 4 days a bag of pure radon will be highly radioactive and quite warm. The ballon will pop, you'll develop some nasty burns, and you'll probably receive a lethal dose of radiation. If you were able to inhale it, you'd die very unpleasantly in quite short order.

Comment: @StarfishPrime, There's probably not that many atoms of Radon in a balloon at atmospheric pressure. It also should leave your lungs quickly after you continue breathing, so I wonder if it would actually be that bad. I am also not sure if the balloon would hold. What would cause it to pop? The heat from radiation, or the high-energy alpha particles?

Comment: @AngryMuppet,I don't understand why you voted to close this question. My question may have several parts, but they encompass one main idea; the viability of a Radon filled balloon, which is obviously a fictional concept. Why is it problematic to answer those at once? I have looked through the How to ask section and found nothing that validates closing my question.

Comment: @elemtilas, It is hurtful that you say I haven't done basic research. I always google all of my questions before I post on stackexchange. If you have a googled resource related to the properties of a radon balloon, please share it with me. Furthermore, the problem I'm trying to solve is obvious, the properties of a radon balloon, an obviously fictitious concept. Why is that not relevant to worldbuilding?

Comment: I voted to close the question because: 1) It's not a single focused question. 2) It lacks any *worldbuilding context*. Just saying it's for a world you're building is insufficient, we need to know the context to avoid [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and to ensure that the answer is the one you're after. 3) The properties of radon are listed clearly on the Wikipedia page - without worldbuilding context this becomes a pure real-world science question of the "satisfy my curiosity" type - which is not what we do here. @Rafael

Comment: The purpose the downvote is, literally, to indicate that the "question does not show any research effort". Less than five minutes spent with wikipedia, google, and youtube can answer every single one of your many questions! *Literally,* there are videos showing people breathing in noble (and other super heavy) gasses and talking. There are videos showing exactly what happens when you fill balloons with a variety of noble gasses and drop them. There are videos that show what happens when you float an air balloon upon a heavy gas.

Comment: @Rafael 1 liter of pure radon contains ~10g of gas and therefore ~2.7x10^22 atoms. Pure radon-222 with a half-life of 3.8215 days has an initial activity (eg. disintegrations per second) of 5.7x10^16 Bq. Each disintegration releases ~5.6MeV of energy and an alpha particle. If you inhale the gas, given the poor penetration of alpha particles, all of the radiation will be absorbed by the lining of your lungs.

Comment: @Rafael contrast with [polonium-210](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polonium-210) which has a similar decay mode but is >36 times _less radioactive than radon_. A single microgram of polonium-210 can kill a human. 1g of po-210 generates 140W of heat, so 10g of pure radon might be generating tens of _kilowatts_ of heat.

Comment: @Rafael oh yeah, and the [decay chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon#Daughters) has lots of short-lived radioisotopes, too. Even if you were inhaling microgram doses of radon, instead of whole-gram doses (and such a thing is likely to be a risk around your magical radon manufactuary), your life expectancy is going to be sharply curtailed.

Comment: @elemtilas, you are the one who didn't do your research. It is clear from my question 'try to souund like darth vader', that I *understood* you'd get a deep voice. I deliberately left my question open-ended to allow for answers like how deep it would sound, as well as (as you can tell from my conversation with starfish prime) what would be the health effects.

Comment: @StarfishPrime, You've convinced me that the balloon is going to pop. No balloon is going to withstand kilowatts of heat! The health effects are probably more difficult to calculate. They would depend on multiple factors, such as how long the Radon stays in your lungs as well as the amount inhaled and pressure etc, but we can agree it definitely wouldn't be good for you.

Comment: @Rafael nah, pretty certain it'll burn the lining of the lungs and you'll asphyxiate. Even if your lungs were heat and radiation proof, you'd absorb a lethal dose of radon and radon decay products into your blood stream and be death within 24 hours. Xenon readily diffuses through lung tissue and can be used in anesthesia... radon is heavy, but it is still a monomolecular gas so it'll get in your bloodstream way easier than sulfur hexafluoride, etc. You'll be buried in a nuclear waste repository within the week.

Comment: In stead of arguing, it might be best to work on *fixing* your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Would it be incredibly heavy?"**

Yes, it would, [just look at how xenon balloons fall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLrofyj6a2s).

**"What if I breathed it in and tried to sound like darth vader"**

Well, you would have a VERY deep voice, [ever seen someone inhale sulfer hexafluoride?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7XdOyZIkko&t=185s) Well Sulfer Hexafluoride has density of 6 kg/m^3, radon's density is 9, almost 10 kg/m^3. Also, they would die. Not only is radon radioactive, it also decays into solid radioactive stuff that would stay in your lungs, giving you all sorts of fun problems like lung cancer.

**"What about radiation? Would it become hot to the touch, or cause the balloon to burst? (And what would happen over time, as the Radon decays?"**

Well, the radon would decay in a matter of days into radioactive dust, so this balloon would be short-lived.

I don't think the radiation would be deadly, because everything I find about the dangers of radon focuses on the greater danger, which is inhaling it.

I can't find anything on the heat that radon produces, although I would guess that at best, you could feel a faint warmth if you pressed your face against the balloon.

Comment: Best practice is to not answer queries that are so close to being closed. Especially when there is no obvious fictional context. This is a basic real world science question.

Comment: ah, okay.       [extra characters so exceeds 15 character limit]